# How to make a css compatible by all browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

i'm developing an header like:

[image: header]

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base1.css">
        <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
        <title>Crociere sul web - Ricerca avanzata</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="header_content">
                <div id="text">
                    NAME OF COMPANY
                </div>
                <div id="header_prenotazioni">
                    My prenotation
                </div>
                <div id="header_phone">
                    <img id="phone" src="images/logo/logo_phone.png" /><b>xxxxxxxxxx</b>
                </div>
                <script>
                    ( function(d, s, id) {
                            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                            if (d.getElementById(id))
                                return;
                            js = d.createElement(s);
                            js.id = id;
                            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1";
                            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
                </script>
                <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/xxxx" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="20" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></div>
                <div id="area_agenzie">
                    <div align="center">
                        AGENCY AREA
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

div#header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0170a8;
    color: white;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div#header_content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90em;
    overflow: hidden;

    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;

}
div#text{
    float:left;
}

div#header_prenotazioni {
    margin-left: 100px;
    border-left: 1px dotted white;
    border-right: 1px dotted white;
    padding-left: 6px;
    float:left;
    padding-right: 6px;

}
div#header_phone {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-right: 1px dotted white;
    padding-right: 6px;
    float:left;
}
div#header_phone img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
div#area_agenzie {
    background-color: #b5c85f;
    color: #0170a8;
    height: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
div#area_agenzie div {
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding-left:2px;

    padding-right:2px;

}
```

My problem is that is not compatible with IE.. the `AGENCY AREA` goes on next row... how can i solve it? can someone help me? thanks!!!

Comment: Having problems with Internet Explorer is normal and expected. Don't feel too bad. It's the worst browser on the planet and the thorn in every web developer's side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using `float: left` for most of them, and `display: inline-block` for the last one. Since you have a fixed-width container, it seems like IE's font rendering is just enough to send the last block to the next line.

Instead, try replacing all those `float: left` with `display: inline-block`, and instead of having `width: 90em`, try `text-align: center;`. This should make everything appear on one line.

Comment: it works! but i have to set width of header_content to 95em. but the div is not totally center into page :/